# JpaReposiotry.save() создает копию объекта, которую и сохраняет

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Есть родительский объект

```
@Entity
class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> children;

    public void addCHild(Child child){
        children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }
...
}

@Entity
class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Parent parent;

            ...
}
```

При таком вызове

```
Parent parent = parentRepository.findById(id);
Child child = new Child();
parent.addCHild(child);
parentRepository.save(parent);
```

Дочерний объект сохраняется, но сохраняется его копия. Потому child.getId() будет null.
Как правильно сохранять дочерние объекты?

Comment: попробуйте сначала сохранить `Child`, а потом добавить его к паренту и сохранить парента.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3927091/4444092

Comment: @Tsyklop и это нормальная практика дв выхова сохранения делать? А если объектов 100? ПОчему оно рекурсивно сохраняет, но не связывает объекты

Comment: @Tsyklop, что такое `CascadeType.PERSIST` Вам видимо не известно. Зачем тогда "пытаетесь" что-то посоветовать?

Comment: Метод `save()` в `CrudRepository` возвращает сущность. И вот что написано в описании метода: `Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely`. Если по-русски, то дальнейшие операции нужно проводить с обьектом, который возвращается методом `save()`.

Comment: @notaProgrammer а ссылку Вы наверно не увидели? или как? по ссылке ответ уже дан.

Comment: @notaProgrammer тогда получается, что возмоности получить сохраненный дочерний объект после save нет :\

Comment: @Tsyklop а при чем тут ссылка? Я про Ваш первый коммент

Comment: Почему нет возможности? Метод save() возвращает сохраненного parent-а, у него можно достать нужного child-a